# Multiple Node Variants with Different Paths

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

I have my node content type set up using Page Manager. I have different variants for this content type that pass different arguments to my view.  Is there any way to have these variants have different URLs? For example:

```
my/node/path
editors/my/node/path
retailers/my/node/path
my/node/path/anotheridentifier
```

The content will be different so I don't see an issue with SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating aliases that point to the same path (your page manager page). To create aliases go to Configuration > Search and metadata > URL aliases

Comment: If I create multiple aliases to a node it always redirects to the main one so I don't think this will work.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding how page_manager works, I thought that the point of creating variants is that they are all invoked using the same path, and the page_manager module chooses which specific variant to display based on the Selection Rules you define when you create each variant. Is this not the case with your situation?

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/node/1583366

Comment: Yes you are correct.  I don't think it is possible what I'm trying to do.